# Appscript to update values from source sheet to target sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an appscript that would copy data from source_sheet into target_sheet. There are 4 columns (Team, Name, Age, Score). I am trying to make the appscript check for changes and use the column Name as the unique identifier. The issue is if someone updates a value (e.g. score), the appscript will not update any chances but new rows only.

```
function copy_rows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("source_sheet");
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('target_sheet');
  const targetLastRow = getColumnHeight(9, targetSheet, ss);
  let lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow, 4);

  Logger.log(lastRow);
  let targetCounter = 1;

  let targetColumnUniqueIdentifier = targetSheet.getRange(1, 9, targetLastRow + 1, 1).getValues();
  let existingValuesInTargetSheet = targetColumnUniqueIdentifier.flat();

  for (var i = 0; i < sourceRange.getValues().length; i++) {
    let rowValues = sourceRange.getValues()[i];
    let id = rowValues[1]; // Unique identifier is in 1st array

    if (existingValuesInTargetSheet.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + targetCounter, 8, 1, 4).setValues([rowValues]);
      targetCounter++;
      existingValuesInTargetSheet.push(id);
    } else {
      // Check for updates in Columns C, E, and F
      let sourceID = rowValues[1]; // Get the source ID from column 2
      let targetID = rowValues[3]; // Get the target ID from column 4
      let sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(i + 2, 3, 1, 3).getValues()[0]; // Get the values in Columns C, E, and F from the source sheet
      let targetValues = targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + targetCounter, 8, 1, 3).getValues()[0]; // Get the values in Columns H, J, and K from the target sheet

      // Compare source and target values and update target sheet if necessary
      if (JSON.stringify(sourceValues) !== JSON.stringify(targetValues)) {
        targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + targetCounter, 8, 1, 3).setValues([sourceValues]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Google Sheet Example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bZo4I76eOivsCL_3d2C4mVJ0Pj8nvhDME-OnRKxS2p8/edit#gid=1797796521)

[Entire Pastebin Link.](https://pastebin.com/EjGfnefL)

Comment: So these are columns C,D,E and F in your source sheet?

Comment: @Cooper, I am trying to update Columns H, J, K in target_sheet based on values in Columns C, E, F in source_sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer to your question but I believe I found some errors in the code.

This:

```
let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow, 4);
```

should be:

```
let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow - 1, 4);
```

This:

```
let targetColumnUniqueIdentifier = targetSheet.getRange(1, 9, targetLastRow + 1, 1).getValues();
```

should be this:

```
let targetColumnUniqueIdentifier = targetSheet.getRange(1, 9, targetLastRow , 1).getValues();
```